# Is using Extension methods to add implementation to an interface Anti-OOP?

Tags: c#, oop

I have an Interface.  Due to a new requirement, the interface now has a single method that could be implemented.

```
public static string ToEntityConnectionString(this IEnvironmentProvider provider)
//Converts a standard connection string to EntityFramework compatible string
```

I could convert the interface to an Abstract class, albeit I'm now restricting myself to this class as the inheriting class.  Although, this interface is currently used for Dependency Injection alone.

After some thought, I realized I could append the functionality to the interface via an Extension method.  It seems to good to be true.  Adding implementation to an interface?  Is it considered a bad practice to  do such a thing?  If so, why?  Considering the circumstances, what should be used instead?

Comment: Extension methods truly are magical. You can abuse all sorts of inheritance structures and so on by using them. The reason is because they are just static methods. It's a combination of syntax sugar and IntelliSense that allow them to be bolted onto just about anything imaginable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why adding the new method to the interface isn't an option.  Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: As long as you don't need the method to access internal state of the instance, an extension method can be very useful.

Comment: @Dejas - Standard OO methodology doesn't allow interfaces to have implementations.  I'm trying to determine if using an extension method in such a way is Anti-OOP.  I mean from a conceptual, design standpoint.  I realize we're dealing with syntactic sugar.

Comment: IEnumerable itself has an extension class Enumerable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have an extension method on an interface you shouldn't think of it as adding an implementation to that interface.  It is just a static helper method that takes an interface, and does all of it's work based on the Interface's exposed members.  This is something you see quite a lot of in OO design; it's not contrary to OO principles.  The 'extension' part just makes it look prettier and makes it easier to find/type out.  If you start to actually think of the extension method as a part of the interface you'll have bigger problems, because it really isn't.

Comment: Perhaps I'm getting caughtup in the intellisense trap.  Because the dot operator gives me the extension method I want to think of the method as a member.  If I modeled the application in UML I suppose I should exclude the extension from the `IEnvironmentProvider` diagram.

Comment: In a UML diagram the extension method would be in the [static] class that defined it, not what it's extending.

Answer (score 1):

I see extension methods as simply helper methods who could just as easily be done with copy paste code by the users of the class. If the functionality can be performed WITHOUT accessing non-public attributes, then is there really anything new being provided that would justify adding it to the interface, then no.